# Showing a link grid heading on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a grid that, on hover of each division, shows the heading. The h4's need to start off hidden and preferably use fadeIn and fadeOut rather than show() or hide(). One issue I got with fadein and fadeout is, if you hover over a few of them quickly enough it seems to add the requests up and start flashing.

There will be more divisions added later.

The HTML:

```
            <div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_10.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_11.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_12.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
```

and the JQuery so far:

```
$(".grid-section").hover(
  function(){
$(this).show();
  },function(){
$(this).hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css. A little bit less effort for your visitor's browser.
[CSS transitions at W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Update: There are lots of ways to do it with jQuery! I've added a function that invokes the css. You can test it by removing the css ':hover' and ':focus' rules. Hope this helps you see what's happening.
More info: [jQuery find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) & [jQuery toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/), also [CSS focus-within](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/) for painless accessibility improvements.

```js
$( '.grid-section' ).hover( function() {
  $( this ).find( 'h4' ).toggleClass( 'hover' );
});
```

```css
.grid-section {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: slategray;
    text-align: center;
}
.grid-section h4 {
    color: transparent;
    transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
.grid-section h4.hover, .grid-section:hover h4, .grid-section:focus-within h4 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_10.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_11.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-section col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <span>
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="images_grid/Grid_Set_01_12.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%" >
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                   <h4 class="card-title grid-pad-p text-center">Rwanda</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Just out of curiosity is it fairly simple to do it with jquery? I would love to know how.

Comment: Updated my reply for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much!